# How to create multiple machines with Homestead-Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I want to have multiple separated machines of Homestead-Laravel (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead). I know that I could have more sites in machines, but idea is to create just one site per machine.

I know that this is possible in Vagrant: (https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/index.html). I have tried it on CentOS machine, and it is working.

Comment: Yes, I can guarantee you that someone has tried.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I know :) Maybe I didn't ask the right question :) How to setup it will be right one.

Comment: What did you try on Homestead-Laravel?  Were you able to get part way there? It might help clarify your question if you gave a sense of what you have already tried and whether any of it worked.